# Spark 2 step join

Tags: apache-spark, join, dataframe

I have two dataframes that I wish to join based on two keys. In case there is no match, I also want to bring in a match based on key 1 only (there could be multiple records for key 1, can choose any one, but only one record should be brought in)

Like so:

```
    val df1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize( List( ("k0","k00","v0"),
    ("k1","k11","v1"),("k2","k22","v2") ) 
    ).toDF("key1","key2","val_type_a")

    val df2 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize( List( ("k0","k00","X"),
    ("k1","XX","Y"),("k1","YY","Z"),("k2","ZZ","W") ) 
    ).toDF("key1","key2","val_type_b")



    val df1_df2=df1.join(df2,Seq("key1","key2"),"left")
    df1.show
    df1_df2.show
```

[image: Res]

But for k1, and k2 rows, I want val_type_b also populated since partial matches based on just key 1 are available-for k1, it could be either Y or Z and for k2 it is W.
Most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in 2 joins : first you joins on 2 columns then join the remaining on 1 column.

Once you have done your fist join you can use groupBy + first on df2 to keep only one value (the first)

```
var df2_single = df2.groupby("key1).agg(first("val_type_b").alias("val_type_b"))
```

Select the missing values (where the first join did not work) :

```
var missing = df1_df2.filter(col("val_types_b").isNull).drop("val_types_2")
```

Then do your left join again :

```
var df1_df2_missing = missing.join(df2_single, "key1", "left" )
```

And union the result from first join and second join :

```
df1_df2 = df1_df2.filter(col("val_types_b").isNotNull).union(df1_df2_missing)
```